# Alternative declaring the file pointer instead FILE * pointer in C

Tags: c, file, pointers

I am looking for a alternative for declaring the file pointer without using "FILE * pointer", so I mean without using the IO standard library function, maybe as a function.

With the library its easy but how could the function look like without the library.
Can somebody give an advice?

Comment: `typedef FILE MY_FILE`

Comment: if you know anything that doesn't use C std library, or anything that is not using C functions underneath, and also high-level please let us know.

Comment: @hagubear - Assembly ;P

Also possibly Ada?

Comment: since for the program FILE * most of the time is opaque you might declare it as void * but what's the point ? code obfuscation ?

Comment: If you don't want to use stdio, just use POSIX open/read/write calls and integer file descriptors.

Comment: You would have to use OS specific system calls and whatever they use for a file handle.

Comment: XY problem. What do you need?

Comment: You're asking how to drive a screw without using a screwdriver. The best answer anyone can give you is "use a screwdriver"; that's what it's for. What actual problem are you trying to solve? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/167210

Comment: @KeithThompson    Starting a revolution probably

Comment: I only wnat to check if a file exits with a seperate function which will do the same like "FILE* Pointer"

Comment: and later want to copy the content with int copy(char* source ,char* target)

Comment: ok I have to use low level functions in C, I think that will do it

Comment: Which platform are you using (Windows, Linux, ...) ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I am using Linux

Comment: @MichaelWalz I simple want to create a function that will to the same like File *...

Comment: Lee Daniel Crocker's comment is for you.

Answer (score 0):

glibc includes a [low-level file API](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Low_002dLevel-I_002fO.html) for handling files with `int` file descriptors.

In fact, I think if you were to cast a `FILE*` to an integer in the glibc implementation, you would obtain a file descriptor usable with the low-level file API, and vise versa.

Comment: This is completely absurd. A `FILE *` object is a _pointer_ to a complex structure in memory, and a file descriptor is a simple integer. In fact, the very page you link to actually describes the library functions you need to use to go between `FILE *` and file descriptor.